# Swift NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot Reload Section

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am currently learning DiffableDataSource. I am using **NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot()**, not `NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot()` to create sections for my dataSource

Depending on which section is being clicked, i want to increase section model data `counter` property. However, I face issue when reloading the section using the `sectionSnapshot()`. The total `counter` property later on will be displayed as sectionHeader.

Below are my structs

```
struct TestParent: Hashable {
    var title = String()
    var counter = 0
    var children = [TestChildren]()
}

struct TestChildren: Hashable {
    var title = String()
    var name = String()
}
```

Below are my implementation codes

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
private var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<AnyHashable, AnyHashable>?
private var parents = [TestParent]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.createSampleArray()
    self.configureAllCollectionViews()
}

fileprivate func createSampleArray() {
    self.parents = [
        TestParent(title: "Parent 1",
                   children: [
                    TestChildren(title: "Child 1 - A"),
                    TestChildren(title: "Child 1 - B"),
                    TestChildren(title: "Child 1 - C"),
                   ]),
        TestParent(title: "Parent 2",
                   children: [
                    TestChildren(title: "Child 2 - A"),
                    TestChildren(title: "Child 2 - B"),
                    TestChildren(title: "Child 2 - C"),
                    TestChildren(title: "Child 2 - D"),
                   ]),
    ]
}

private func parentSnapshot(_ parent: TestParent) -> NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot<AnyHashable> {
    var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot<AnyHashable>()
    snapshot.append(parent.children)
    return snapshot
}

private func applyInitialSnapshot() {
    for eachParent in parents {
        self.dataSource?.apply(self.parentSnapshot(eachParent), to: eachParent)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.check(indexPath: indexPath)
    }
    
 fileprivate func check(indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let children = self.dataSource?.itemIdentifier(for: indexPath) as? TestChildren else { return }
        guard var section = self.dataSource?.snapshot().sectionIdentifier(containingItem: children) as? TestParent else { return }
        
        section.counter += 1
        var snapshot = self.dataSource?.snapshot()
        snapshot?.reloadSections([section])
        self.dataSource?.apply(snapshot!)
    }
```

How can I update the section data model `counter` property upon every cell click? There is no problem on building the collectionView UI

What am I missing here? Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your section is a struct—a value type—so when you change the section count, you change the hash that the diffable data source is using as the identifier. It doesn’t know that you are updating a preexisting section; it thinks it is a brand new section.

In general, section identifiers should be *identifiers* and not contain mutable state. You can write your hash and equality methods to ignore that mutable state, but thinking about it is a pain, so just keep the actual data elsewhere and look it up based on the section identifier.

Comment: ahh.. that is why... Thanks Sir for the explanation. really appreciate it!